# Add prefix to strings matching a specific pattern

Tags: regex, pandas

Based on a DataFrame that contains dates

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'month':['2','5','8'],'year':['2001',' 89','1999']})
print(df)
  month  year
0     2  2001
1     5    89
2     8  1999
```

I want to prefix all year instances consisting of only 2 digits by `19`, such that the resulting DataFrame is

```
  month  year
0     2  2001
1     5  1989
2     8  1999
```

I tried

```
pattern = r'[^\d]*\d{2}[^\d]*'
replacement = lambda m: '19'+m
df.year = df.year.str.replace(pattern,replacement)
print(df)
    month  year
0     2   NaN
1     5   NaN
2     8   NaN
```

Which does not work. What is the problem?

Comment: `df['year'] = df['year'].str.strip().apply(lambda x: '19' + x if len(x) == 2 else x)`?

Comment: Are you sure it should be prefixed with `19` in all cases?

Comment: Yes, you may assume that all 2 digit instances need to be prefixed by 19.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^\d]` requires there to be a character which is not a digit. But then you say this can be repeated zero times, which of course trivially is also true when there are more than two digits. You want to match `^\d{2}$` instead.

(Also, `[^\d]` is better written `\D`.)

A numeric comparison is probably much better than a regex here, though. Simply check if the number is smaller than 100.

Comment: No, `[^\d]*` does not *require*  anything as `*` matches *zero* or more chars.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback; rephrased.

Answer (score 1):

The `lambda m: '19'+m` is wrong because `m` is a `MatchData` object, not a string. You might have tried `m.group()`, but since you also match any non-digit chars on both ends of a number (as whitespace) you might still get wrong results.

You may use

```
df['year'] = df['year'].str.strip().str.replace('^\d{2}$', r'19\g<0>')
```

NOTES:

- You need to get rid of leading/trailing whitespace with `str.strip()`
- You need to match all strings that consist of just 2 digits with `^\d{2}`
- The replacement is a concatenation of `19` and the match value (`\g<0>` is the whole match backreference).

Answer (score 0):

Count strings that has a length of two and prefix it with 19:

```
df.assign(year = np.where(df.year.str.strip().str.len()==2,
                          '19'+df.year.str.strip(),
                           df.year))


    month   year
0   2   2001
1   5   1989
2   8   1999
```